# How to use a configurable Where Clause in a Kentico Query

Tags: c#, kentico

I currently assign the sql statement to a NVarchar and then execute it. But I don't like the way how this works.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @sqlStatement NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @sqlStatement = N'
     SELECT *
     FROM CMS_User usr
     WHERE
     (    
          usr.LastName LIKE ''%' + @Search + '%'' OR
     )'

IF(@SearchWhereClause IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
     SET @sqlStatement = @sqlStatement+  N' AND (' + @SearchWhereClause + ')'
END

SET @sqlStatement = @sqlStatement+  N' ORDER BY usr.LastName'

EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @sqlStatement
```

**Code**

```
 QueryDataParameters parameters = new QueryDataParameters();
 parameters.Add("@Search", prefixText);

 //set configurabel searchWhereClause
 string searchWhereClause = SettingsKeyProvider.GetStringValue("WhereClause");
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchWhereClause))
 {
      searchWhereClause = null;
 }
 parameters.Add("@SearchWhereClause", searchWhereClause);

 DataSet ds = ConnectionHelper.ExecuteQuery("custom.DocType.Query", parameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can use the Kentico macros for queries:

**SQL**

```
SELECT * 
FROM CMS_User usr
WHERE 
(   
    usr.LastName LIKE '%' + @Search + '%' OR 
)
AND ( usr.UserIsHidden IS NULL OR usr.UserIsHidden = 0 )
AND ( ##WHERE## )
ORDER BY usr.LastName
```

**Code**

```
ConnectionHelper.ExecuteQuery(string queryName, QueryDataParameters parameters,
   string where);
```